How to suppress QAC cross module warnings?
How can I suppress QAC cross module warnings? see image below.
(for example multiple static variables with the same name in different translation units)

used QAC version is 8.1.2
edit:
I can configure QAC with files located in out project ending with: .p_a, .p_c, .p_d and .p_s
but I don't want to suppress these warnings globally for whole project, I want to suppress these specific 12 warnings.
For example this is one of the warnings because we have static localData_t localData; in two translation units (this is the case also for two static functions with the same name across translation units):
1527 Object/function with internal linkage has same identifier as another object/function with internal linkage.
I have tried:
/* PRQA S 1527 ++ */
static localData_t localData;
/* PRQA S 1527 -- */

in both translation units where localData is defined, but without success.

Is QAC configurable? Lint tools I've used let you switch off individual warnings.

Please [edit] your question to remove the noise and add a [mre]. Most probably you do not want to suppress the warnings, because they point to an implementation problem. in this case chances are that you define variables at multiple places, which can result in multiple instances what should be one. It is almost always calling for disaster to suppress warnings.

@thebusybee The noise is there because of bad site design. Apparently you can't post a question which is mostly pictures. I tried to edit it out, but no go. So I can't really blame the OP.

@Lundin Well, I cannot agree. A question with mostly pictures is bad from the start, so I think it is a good web site design that one cannot post such. As we see, only some more characters are expected, and are actually necessary to make this an acceptable question. (Even without the screenshot it is a bad question, and the screenshot does not add any relevant information.)

@thebusybee I understand the question perfectly fine, no need to add pointless text for the heck of it. I just haven't been using QAC much so I can't answer it.

@Lundin At least a chapter number of the documentation related to suppressing warnings, accompanied with a reason why it does not help, would show the effort invested. And the obligatory [mre] would fulfill the text requirement super easily. -- However, as I wrote, suppressing warnings is almost always the wrong way, so we need to see the code to judge.

@thebusybee Suppressing warnings is standard practice when working with static analyzers and MISRA C. These tools have way too many false positives to at all function in default mode. Additionally you might want to ignore certain MISRA C rules as per your own take on that standard (company-wide deviations).

@Lundin Yeah, I know your aversion against rules. :-D And MISRA is some special case...

@thebusybee If you have worked with static analyzers at all, you'll know they need to be fine-tuned manually. These type of products - like compilers - take decades of development to settle. There will be lots of false positives and there will be lots of bugs, no matter which brand you go for.

Does this answer help you, even if it is old? (BTW, are you sure about the comment's syntax? "++" for "disable" looks suspicious.)
